# Creating a list for a Treenode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, extjs4, treenode

I know this must be real easy but I just can't get it to work... I am trying to make a List for extjs Tree by comparing two columns from differnt rows and putting them as a Node or a leaf accordingly. this is my sample data

```
ListA  ListB  labelName
 NY           Parent1
        NY    Leaf1
 HI           Parent2
 AK           Parent3
```

and this is my c# end... so when I match NY, I am supposed to have Parent1 as node and Leaf1 as its leaf and not for HI or AK... but doing this throws me all data as Parent.. even the leaf.

```
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            comd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = comd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                City MyData = new City();

                MyData.ListA = reader["ListA"].ToString().Trim();
                MyData.ListB = reader["ListB"].ToString().Trim();
                MyData.labelName = reader["labelName"].ToString().Trim();
                giveData.Add(MyData);
            }

            int count = 1;

            List<TreeNode> myNode = new List<TreeNode>();
            foreach (City MyData in giveData)
            {
                // 1st foreach
                    if (MyData.ListA != "")
                    {

                        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
                        treeNode.id = count++;
                        treeNode.name = MyData.labelName;
                        treeNode.leaf = false;

                        List<TreeNode> Level1 = new List<TreeNode>();
                        foreach (City labelName  in giveData)
                        {
                            if (labelName.ListA == labelName.ListB)
                            {// 2nd foreach
                                TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode();
                                node1.id = count++;
                                node1.name = labelName.labelName;
                                node1.leaf = true;

                                Level1.Add(node1);
                            }
                        }

                        treeNode.children = Level1;
                        myNode.Add(treeNode);
                }
            }
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myNode);
```

Should I use array to store each record and compare them instead... I am out of ideas... I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this... Please help

Comment: ... I'm a bit confused - How would you know which node the leaf "NY" (Leaf1) goes with? Based upon the number (Leaf1 goes with Parent1) or by the location in the list? ... will a leaf node always be a blank in List A?

Comment: Hi John... if the value matches, ListA goes as Parent and ListB goes as leaf

Comment: And so you want a tree that looks as follows Node1:Parent1 - Leaf1; Node2: Parent2; Node3: Parent2? I'm just a bit confused on the final output??

Comment: Yes, anything that is on list B goes as a Leaf..so in the above data... Node1:Parent1 - Leaf1; Node2: Parent2; Node3: Parent3... I just realized a typo in my data.. should be Parent3

Comment: ... I posted a solution in VB, but looking at your code (just by guessing), if you replaced `if (labelName.ListA == labelName.ListB)` to `if (MyData.ListA == labelName.ListB)`, I think it would also work...

Comment: Thanks John. I followed what you said here. It works but takes a lot of time to load the tree and crashes. But I have to keep running the script to make it work. Is there a solution to this performance issue.

Comment: I'm a VB guy, but I'll try and update your code and post a new solution in C#... HOPEFULLY I'll get it working - All I can promise, though, is that the logic will be sound :)

Comment: :) Thanks John... I mean i get the results but keeps crashing... I can't think of another way of doing it. I am trying to see if getting the data from the db in a different way may be faster...

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think will be a more efficient way of combining the leaves with parents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data is the way you state and the "parents" will come before any leaves, here's a single pass way I came up with to create the tree:

*[Irrelevant Code Snipped]*

**Update: LINQ using `Dictionary<string, List<TreeNode>>`**

I created a new class TreeNode and some sample data for testing:

```
var MyData = new List<City>
                  {
                     new City {ListA = "AK", ListB = "", labelName = "Alaska"},
                     new City {ListA = "HI", ListB = "", labelName = "Hawaii"},
                     new City {ListA = "", ListB = "HI", labelName = "Hawaii Leaf 1"},
                     new City {ListA = "", ListB = "HI", labelName = "Hawaii Leaf 2"},
                     new City {ListA = "NY", ListB = "", labelName = "New York"},
                     new City {ListA = "", ListB = "NY", labelName = "New York Leaf 1"},
                     new City {ListA = "", ListB = "NY", labelName = "New York Leaf 2"}
                  };
```

Here's the new method that basically creates 2 lists, 1 for the parents and 1 for the leaves. I then loop through the leaves to find any matching parents and add the leaves to it:

```
var index = 0;
var parents = (from p in MyData
               where p.ListB == ""
               select p).ToDictionary(p => p.ListA, p => new TreeNode { id = index++, name = p.labelName, leaf = false });

var leaves = (from l in MyData
              where l.ListA == ""
              group l by l.ListB into stateGroup
              select stateGroup).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

foreach (var leaf in leaves.Where(leaf => parents.ContainsKey(leaf.Key)))
{
    parents[leaf.Key].children =
        leaf.Value.Select(l => new TreeNode {id = index++, name = l.labelName, leaf = true}).ToList();
}

var myNode = parents.Select(p => p.Value).ToList();

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myNode);
```

I think this should be more efficient than using lists and the `List.Find()`

Comment: Thank you CAbbott... I tried your answer... It all works for the node part... but I don't see any leafs..

Comment: Are you sure that the parent nodes are there before the leaf in the data coming back?

Comment: Yes Cabbott... the parent nodes are first and I am getting all the nodes like Parent1, Parent2 and Parent3 but I don't see any leafs

Comment: Hey Cabbott... I got it to work. However it takes forever to get the data on my tree. It crashes, but it works... is there a way to work around that issue

Comment: Thanks CAbbott... I am not sure but I am thinking of trying to use Dictionary might help??? sort of Dictionary<string, TreeNode>...

Comment: Thank you Cabbott... I placed parents and leaves on my method... but my tree does not show anything... am I supposed to create a newList too coz I already have that implemented

Comment: Is my Dictionary defined correctly?? this is how I am doing it...Dictionary<string, List<TreeNode>> mainList = new List<TreeNode>

Comment: Maybe I should modify this to be exactly what you have in the example for class names and properties? Is that what the tree is expecting, specific class and property names?

Comment: I've updated the LINQ example to use data types you had in your question with the same class/variable names

Comment: Thank you CAbbott... your answer really helped... Part of the problem was on my extjs tree rendering too... Thanks a bunch again

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would probably be Linq - I created a quick and dirty VB.Net solution to move you in the right direction - The main part being the SECOND Linq statement...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As New List(Of City)

    x.Add(New City With {.ListA = "NY", .ListB = "", .Leaf = "Parent1"})
    x.Add(New City With {.ListA = "", .ListB = "NY", .Leaf = "Leaf1"})
    x.Add(New City With {.ListA = "HI", .ListB = "", .Leaf = "Parent2"})
    x.Add(New City With {.ListA = "AK", .ListB = "", .Leaf = "Parent3"})

    tv1.Nodes.AddRange((From y In x Where y.ListA <> "" Select New TreeNode With {
                                                                    .Name = y.ListA,
                                                                    .Text = y.Leaf}).ToArray)

    For Each nd As TreeNode In tv1.Nodes
        Dim Nm As String = nd.Name
        nd.Nodes.AddRange((From y In x Where y.ListB = Nm Select New TreeNode(y.Leaf)).ToArray)
    Next
End Sub
```

Simply put, you populate the first ste of parent nodes, then you just loop through all the nodes and populate them with any nodes where ListB = Node's name.

Hope this helps move you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you Jonn... but I am totally using c# and besides, I have about 500 data and 30 parent nodes... :)

Comment: ... I added a comment to your original question with another thought, but my main point here wasn't the code - that's just how i tested it to make sure it worked - It was to populate the first (parent) nodes and then to populate the second using Linq based upon parent name.

Answer (score 1):

... I'm trying to write this in C#, but this should do it:

```
        int count = 1;

        List<TreeNode> myNode = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (City MyData in giveData)
        {
            // 1st foreach
            if (MyData.ListA != "")
            {

                TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
                treeNode.id = count++;
                treeNode.name = MyData.labelName;
                treeNode.leaf = false;

                foreach (City labelName in giveData)
                {
                    if (MyData.ListA == labelName.ListB)
                    {// 2nd foreach
                        TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode();
                        node1.id = count++;
                        node1.name = labelName.labelName;
                        node1.leaf = true;

                        treeNode.Nodes.Add(node1);
                    }
                }

                myNode.Add(treeNode);
            }
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myNode);
```

Hope this at least moves you in the right direction...

Comment: Hi John... on treeNode.Nodes.Add(node1); I am getting an error on 'Nodes'... it says it does not contain a definition

Comment: I atleast got it to run John... I think u probably meant treeNode.children.Add(node1);... However this takes a lot of time to get my data and causes it to crash... Is there a way to do this more efficiently? I am currently trying to use dictionary but no luck